# Help with EtherDelta

Tags: etherdelta

I am trying to buy PPT on EtherDelta but have done something wrong and wonder if it can be reversed.

I successfully transferred ETH from MetaMask to EtherDelta. When I tried to buy PPT, I accidently transferred my ETH from the Deposit column into the Transfer column.  Can I transfer the ETH back into the Deposit column, and what do I do then in order to buy PPT?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give. Please keep it simple as I am not familiar with a lot of the jargon and need step by step instructions.

Comment: By mistake i deposit all the amount of ethereum fom my wallet to etherdelta and even now the transaction isnt completed.What can i do because i even dont know the transaction link

Answer (score 1):

Just withdraw the ETH back into your account (press "Withdraw tab", then type the quantity of ETH and press "Withdraw button").
To buy any token, deposit the token into etherdelta smart contract ("Deposit tab", then "Deposit button") and place an order. There are good tutorials available from the Help dropdown.